# How to keep the active element of scrollable bar always visible?

Tags: scroll, navigation, html-lists

I am building an app in React, which has a sidebar where users can scroll through the elements of the bar using the arrows on the keyboard. When one of the buttons is clicked, the button gets an active tag. When scrooling around using the arrows, I am moving this active class around. The issue is that if I keep scrolling and the list is long enough the selected item can be outside of the visible part of the sidebar. How could I keep the active element always visible? Thanks!
My html structure is the following:

```
<div style="width: 10%; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden scroll;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button order="0" class="btn-block" type="button">test1
            </button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button order="1" class="btn-block active" type="button">test2
            </button>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding an extra ref field to the button and defining a scrollTo function, which is called with the key press handler. The function is the following:

```
scrollTo = (name) => {
        const node = findDOMNode(this.refs[name]);
        scrollIntoView(node, {
            time: 500,
            block: "end",
            behavior: "smooth",
            align: {
                top: 0
            }
        })
    }
```